# Connecting OAuth with User or Person Model in ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-oauth

So there's plenty of tutorials online on how to get oAuth working with ASP.NET, even a tutorial on how to set roles for those logged in accounts with MVC but none of these tutorials explain what's next. What is that called when you connect a user you've registered with Google to the person or user model in your app? How do you act as one of those persons based on who you're logged in as with Google?  I've figured out how to register first and last name and all that jazz but still I'm not sure how to make it so that I'm in or acting as the person.

For example, I have a person model and some other models that inherit from the person model, such as Engineer and Manager:

```
public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The First Name field is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Last Name field is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return FirstName + " " + LastName;
            }
        }

    }

public class Engineer : Person
    {
        public ICollection<Manager> managers { get; set; }
    }

public class Manager : Person
    {
        public ICollection<Engineer> engineers { get; set; }
    }
```

Here I have the following added to the AccountController:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            string firstName;
            string lastName;
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }
            if (loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider == "Google")
            {
                var externalIdentity = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
                var emailClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email);
                var lastNameClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname);
                var givenNameClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName);

                firstName = givenNameClaim.Value;
                lastName = lastNameClaim.Value;

            } else
            {
                firstName = "Error";
                lastName = "Error";
            }
            // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
            var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                    ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                    return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email, FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastName });
            }
```

And the account view model:

```
public class ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

So how do I log in with google and then be one of the persons? What is this even called? Is there a name for doing this? I assume everyone does this at some point. I can create persons, managers and engineers in my initialization class but I don't know how to do it with oAuth.

Note, I would prefer to force all users to log in with Google rather than create a local user account so I didn't bother with registering site accounts.

Also for good measure here's my IdentityModel:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you talking about social logins?

Comment: I'm talking about google oauth. Adding the oauth data to the user or person class.  I've updated my post again with further details.

Comment: During the call of - await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync your external access token is used to generate a local access token. Are you trying to ask about impersonation ?

Comment: Sort of, what I want to know about mainly is how to use oAuth to create accounts within the system and allow an admin or owner of that account to manage their details as well as having those users play different roles. When they hit the register button, I want it to create a person. I have searched Google far and wide for tutorials on this and I can't seem to find any. I can find tutorials on Google oAuth up to signing in, some tips on gathering information from the user or the Google account, but no further than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the external login process, an authorization token is returned by the third party API. You should add this token as a claim for the user. You can do this by changing the code in `Startup.Auth.cs` to something like the following:

```
var googleOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = Properties.Settings.Default.GoogleClientId,
    ClientSecret = Properties.Settings.Default.GoogleClientSecret,
    Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
        {
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:google:access_token", context.AccessToken, XmlSchemaString, "Google"));
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
};
googleOptions.Scope.Add("foo");
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);
```

Where "foo" is above, you'll need to add the scope(s) you need the user to authorize your application for. Consult the Google API docs for a [full list of scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes). If you need multiple scopes, add additional `googleOptions.Scope.Add` lines.

Later, you can retrieve the token using:

```
var googleTokenClaim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ClaimType.EndsWith("google:access_token"));
```

For the purposes of Google's APIs, the token returned is a "refresh token". The refresh token is good until the user revokes access to your app, but you need to "trade it in" for an access token. Details for how to do that can be found in the [Google Identity Platform docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer), or you can just use one of the client libraries to handle all this for you.

Long and short, once you have a true access token, you simply authorize requests that need authorization by adding an `Authorization: Bearer [token]` header to the request.

Now, different APIs handle some of this differently, but you specifically mentioned Google. Consult the docs of other APIs you may need to utilize to see what you should do with those.

**UPDATE: Getting User Instance**

With Identity, the user principal exposed by `User.Identity` is not a complete representation of the user instance in the database. In order to get all the information for a user, including their claims, you need to query the user from the database. First, you need to get the user's id, so you have something to query by. Identity exposes an extension `GetUserId()` on `User.Identity` for that:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

If you've customized the primary key for `IdentityUser`, then you need to use the generic version instead:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
```

In either case, you then use that user id to query the user from the database. You can actually query your context directly, since "users" are just another `DbSet` on `IdentityDbContext`:

```
var user = db.Users.Find(userId);
```

However, you'll most often use an instance of `UserManager` since it essentially wraps your context and provides additional, helpful features:

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(userId);
```

This is based off the default implementation of `AccountController` when you've scaffolded your project with Individual Authentication. By default, the `UserManager` property on `AccountController` is an instance of `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`, or if you've customized the primary key, something like `UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>`, for example, where `int` would be the type of the primary key. If you're doing this in a different controller or simply not using the scaffolded version of `AccountController`, then you just need to similarly define an instance of `UserManager`.

Comment: Where does my person model come into all this?

Comment: It doesn't really, or perhaps it's better to say wherever you want it to. Perhaps I'm not understanding your question entirely, but there's no good way to tie an external login to a non-`IdentityUser` object. Really, if you want the login tied to `Person`, then `Person` should inherit from `ApplicationUser`.

Comment: Let me try getting the person model to inherit from ApplicationUser because that's the only way so far that this makes any sense at all. Yes there's no good way to tie an external login to a non-IdentityUser, but I literally have no idea of ANY way so having a single way would be better than having no way at all. I don't even know what gets executed when a user hits the register button after authenticating with Google and hitting allow and then the register button. You know what I mean? I don't know what happens next. I'll try stepping through and see.

Comment: Mostly, it's just OAuth stuff. If you familiarize yourself with that, that's pretty much all Identity is doing. After authenticating, the provider sends a POST to the "redirect URI". In your AccountController, that's ExternalLoginCallback. There, an IdentityUserLogin record is added, and either associated with the existing user record, or the user is prompted for any additional info necessary to create that record.

Comment: You have user.Claims.FirstorDefault... there as a way to retrieve the token later, but what is the "user" object in this case? Is that System.Security? Because there's no FirstOrDefault method under there.

Comment: `user` would be your `IdentityUser`. You need to retrieve it first, based on `User.Identity.GetUserId()`, from either a `UserManager<TUser>` instance or your context (`Users` property).

Comment: so var user = User.Identity.GetUserId(); ? Something is missing there. I'm totally lost here sorry. I'm new to asp.net mvc. I'm surprised none of the tutorials go over this side of things when it comes to Google oAuth.

Comment: No. That's how you get the user's id. From there you use your `UserManager` instance or your context to fetch the user object from the database.

Comment: Is there any way you can show an example of this in the answer above? I'm baffled and searching and reading around about get user id and I'm not seeing any examples of it being done in the way you're talking about... in fact I'm not quite clear on what you mean.

Comment: I was unable to retrieve the token but I was able to get the user ID inside of the ExternalLoginConfirmation post method after the user was signed in. I used the existing user Id string it retrieves from the new ApplicationUser instance. It simply cannot find the token, constantly getting a null reference exception when I do that. No matter how far into the registration process it is.